# Visual Studio Plugin for Team Explorer (TFS) - How to get a selection in query editor?

Tags: visual-studio, plugins, tfs

I am developing a Visual Studio Plugin to extend TFS Query handling (2012 version).

After a lot of (re)search I am almost done.

What the plugin can do is extend the context menu in the Query Editor. There I can add additional filters, this works. But I would like to insert the filter above the selected row in the editor.

I cannot find a possibility to retrieve this selection.

I fetch the current QUeryDocument with

```
IWorkItemTrackingDocument wtd = GetActiveDocument();
IQueryDocument queryDoc = wtd as IQueryDocument;

public IWorkItemTrackingDocument GetActiveDocument()
{
    object _lockToken = new object(); // token used for locking the document
    if (DTE.ActiveDocument != null)
    {
        string activeDocumentMoniker = DTE.ActiveDocument.FullName;
        IWorkItemTrackingDocument doc = DocService.FindDocument(activeDocumentMoniker, _lockToken);
        if (doc != null)
        {
            doc.Release(_lockToken);
        }
        return doc;
    }

    return null;
}
```

But IQueryDocument does not seem to have a possibility to get the selected rows. There is a SelectedItemIds-Property, but this property contains the selected work item IDs in the results view, not in the query editor.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Klaus

Comment: If you're using Reflector to learn, try finding how the Group/Ungroup tool works...